# Neovim freezes when opening a folder in WSL2

Tags: neovim, performance, wsl

When I open neovim with to show a folder it completely freezes.

- When opening a folder from the command line: `nvim .` I see a completely black screen
- When having a file open, navigating to parent folder `:Ex` - I still see the old file contents.

But in both cases, it no longer responds to keyboard input.

This happens inside WSL2 on Windows.

I have no configuration files, so I'm running a completely vanilla neovim.

What can be the issue, and what can I do to diagnose the issue?

I did experiment with SpaceVim, but I removed the config files in my home folder, so it shouldn't affect my current config. And the installation wasn't sudo'd, so it shouldn't have been able to change some global configuration.

I discovered that this happens when I have a DISPLAY variable set, but no X server running on that host. It doesn't actually open any window on that server if I launch it.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! You can try some of the debugging tips at [How to debug my vimrc](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/2003/10604), specifically the verbose and `-D` tips (I know you said vanilla config, but there are other tidbits in there too). I wonder if reinstalling neovim or trying with regular vim shows the same issue

Comment: Hmmm, I discovered that this happens when I have a `DISPLAY` variable set, but no X server running on that host. It doesn't actually open any window on that server if I launch it.